# Check if a PHP-based SOAP server is FULLY woking

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soapserver

I have a SOAP-Server problem driving me nuts from a couple of days. I have a very simple SOAP-Client PHP script interrogating a simple SOAP-Server PHP script as well.

I have an exact copy of these scripts on my debug server and they work perfecly (it's just a hello World function) but on production seems there's no way to getting a response from soap-server from soap-client. I keep getting "Procedure 'ns1:testHello' not present" error (testHello is the function name).

I know production-client is working because if I make a call from production server to develop WSDL it works perfectly. I do think it's somehow correlated with SOAP server but how can I exaclty know if it's working properly and what's Wrong?

If I take a look infophp() dump I see both SOAP server and client are enabled

```
Soap Client     enabled
Soap Server     enabled 

Directive   Local Value Master Value
soap.wsdl_cache 1   1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir /tmp    /tmp
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled 0   1
soap.wsdl_cache_limit   5   5
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl 0   86400
```

I've tried to force both SOAP_1_1 and SOAP_1_2 versions but no changes.
I've tried disabling every kind of cache but no changes as well.
I've read that "ns:X function not present" is usually dued to a WSDL misconfiguration but how can It be wrong if it's an exact copy (except for targetNamespace, xmlns:tns and soap:address urls pointing to the production server)

**I'm starting to think that is somehow correlated to some web server configuration settings. Any ideas? What kind of tests can I do?**

Thanx a lot in advance.

My SERVER code:

```
    ini_set("display_errors", "off");
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
    ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

    $wsdl_url="http://SITE_URL/test.wsdl";


    function testHello($functionName){
        $return = "Hello, ".$functionName;
      return $return;
    } 

    $server= new SoapServer($wsdl_url, array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
    $server->addFunction("testHello");
    $server->handle();
```

My client code

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);
ini_set("display_errors", "on");

$wsdl_url="http://SITE_URL/test.wsdl";

$client=new SoapClient($wsdl_url , array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));

try{
  $t = $client-> testHello("Test");
  var_dump($t);
} catch(SoapFault $e){
  var_dump($e);
}
```

My WSDL file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<definitions name="TLN"
             targetNamespace="http://SITE_URL/test.wsdl"
             xmlns:tns="http://SITE_URL/test.wsdl"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
             xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

     <message name="testHelloRequest">
        <part name="functionName" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>

    <message name="testHelloResponse">
        <part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>

    <portType name="testHelloPortType">
        <operation name="testHello">
            <input message="tns:testHelloRequest" />
            <output message="tns:testHelloResponse" />
        </operation>
    </portType>

   <binding name="testHelloBinding" type="tns:testHelloPortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <operation name="testHello">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />

            <input>
                <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>

    <documentation>testHello</documentation>

    <service name="testHelloService">
        <port name="testHelloPort" binding="testHelloBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://SITE_URL/server.php" />
        </port>
    </service>       


</definitions>
```

Comment: When I create a soap server I usually test my WSDL file with soapUI.

Comment: It was too easy for me to check my soap server with soapUI, you try it

Comment: Thanx Daan and smarber, I've tried soapUI and makes soap dev easier. By the way seems a server config problem and IT are trying to fix this issue.

Comment: Just a small update in case someone else is intereseted. It seems production server had a still unsolved issue with native SOAP libraries. Went installing nusoap and then is fully working.